# Tomcat8 UTF-8 showing as question mark

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8, tomcat8

***I have read around for days but can't get this solved!***

Ok. I have a webapp that makes a bytearray based on GET parameters and sends it to a server. The reply is then decrypted and I have code that parses it to JSON.

```
InputStream myis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptedPayload);
new Avatar(myis);
```

`decryptedPayload` is a byte[].

Some characters are foreign characters, for example, Russian or Chinese. These just don't get sent properly through the GET parameters or when I'm receiving stuff and printing it out...

For example here is a UTF-8 character ж
And when I try and pass it through the GET parameter I get no proper response.
[http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/search?search=ж](http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/search?search=%D0%B6)
As you can see the `ж` is getting changed to a `?` and then returning no results where as if that character was actually sent it should return results.

I am using Tomcat8. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

***UPDATE***

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Character encoding test page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Data posted to this form was:
     <%
       request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       out.print(request.getParameter("mydata"));
     %>

     </p>
     <form method="POST" action="test.jsp">
       <input type="text" name="mydata">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I did this on Localhost which has the same config as my production server by the way.
[http://localhost:8080/Api/test.jsp?mydata=жä](http://localhost:8080/Api/test.jsp?mydata=%D0%B6%C3%A4)
Outputs "Data posted to this form was: жä" so it did work as it should...

***Edit 2:***

http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/test?data=%D0%B6%C3%A4

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public test() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("data"));
    }

}
```

***UPDATE 3***

Ok in the servlet I changed `response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("data"));` to `response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("data") +"\n"+ "¢");` and I now have this output:

> Ð¶Ã¤
>
> Â¢

Comment: Well we can't see *any* of the source you're using, which makes it very hard to tell what's wrong. I suggest you write a short servlet which *just* echoes the original query, and also includes a hard-coded non-ASCII character. That should help you to identify whether the problem is understanding the query or returning the data in the response.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I've given you an idea: show us some code, so we're in a better position to help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet see my edit ;)

Comment: Ah, we didn't even know it was a JSP. Where do you get to configure the content-type (including encoding) for JSP? Basically you want to set the encoding on the response before you get to the JSP part...

Comment: @JonSkeet the Webapp is a servlet. The JSP is just what the tomcat documentation says to use for checking.

Comment: Then I would suggest getting rid of JSP from the problem, and writing a *trivial* servlet to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ok see my edit @JonSkeet

Comment: Right - and could you *also* print out a hard-coded non-ASCII character (as per my suggestion this morning)? Because at that point, if it works, we'd have proved that the problem is within `request.getParameter`, *not* the output...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93075/discussion-between-shivam-paw-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: I notice that the documentation for `ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding` overrides the encoding used in the *body* of the request - so that wouldn't include the query string.

Comment: @JonSkeet see my edit :)

Comment: @JonSkeet check our chat. I think I got what you wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Your request is defaulting to:

`Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1`

Try setting all char encoding to UTF8 in [Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8) to test this.

And UTF-8 escape your request so: ж is %u0436

http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=%u0436

The above URL returns a lot of json information with this search parameter encoded.

You can use an online tool like [this one](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) to test.

Comment: I was looking at that but it didn't seem to work properly :(

Comment: I will have another look though

Comment: Now searching for `http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=ä` gives a black diamond with a question mark in it...

Comment: http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/clan?clan=4296743896 some do however seem to be working

Comment: @ShivamPaw see edit: if you cannot set the charset, then you can encode the GET request parameters

Comment: http://185.112.249.77:9999/Api/Search?search=%u0436 has gone to the default "clan" not the symbol..